# What is the right and efficient way of displaying images based on name in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm really new to Django. I'm having difficulty displaying images based on their name and according to the url pattern.

So basically the url consists of several variables within them and I want to be able to use that to fetch a particular image that is named with those variables.

**Example:**

```
localhost:8080/farm/chicken
```

this would fetch an image inside of my *../static/images/* folder and get:

```
farm_chicken.jpg
```

**Another example:**

```
localhost:8080/zoo/alligator
```

would get:

```
zoo_alligator.jpg
```

I can fetch the url parameters. So, should I make these image names within my `views.py` file and pass the names (zoo_alligator) into a context to be retrieved by the template later on? Would this be the correct way?

Thank you for your advice everybody! I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, should I make these image names within my views.py file and pass
>   the names (zoo_alligator) into a context to be retrieved by the
>   template later on? Would this be the correct way?

Sure, this is one way to do it. Something like this:

```
(r'show/(?P<in_path>.*)$','someapp.image_view')
```

Then in `image_view`:

```
def image_view(request,in_path):
    img = in_path.replace('/','_')+'.jpg'
    return render(request,'some_template.html',{'path':img})
```

However, as your view is very simple - you can pass the path directly to the template from `urls.py`, using [`direct_to_template`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template):

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

(r'show/(?P<in_path>.*)$',direct_to_template,{'template':'some_template.html'})
```

In `some_template.html`:

```
<img src="{{ params.in_path }}">
```

The problem is that you won't get your string formatting done as the default filters do not have a "replace" function. You can easily write a custom filter:

```
@register.filter
@stringfilter
def format_path(the_path):
    return the_path.replace('/','_')+'.jpg'
```

Then modify the template:

```
<img src="{{ params.in_path|format_path }}">
```

You should read the documentation on [writing custom filters and tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) for more details including where to store the filter code to make sure django can find it.

Comment: Kalid I got it to work out my way by fetching the url and using it's name to dynamically fetch each image.

But sadly. I wasn't able to get it to load just normal static files that are not dynamically fetched.. :(

i keep getting  a `Invalid block tag: 'static', expected 'endblock'` error... still haven't been able to figure out where my problem is.

Comment: You are missing `{% load static %}` at the top of your template.

Comment: when I extended the base.html it already has that in there. Do I really need it again?

Answer (score 2):

You won't actually do something like that, in general.  What you should do is to send the image as a context variable from your view function to your template.

If you are using your url node to determine which picture to show, then in your corresponding view function, you are actually using "alligator" or "chicken" to load up the corresponding `Animal` class.

Once the correct `animal` object is instantiated, you could send this animal object to your django template and load in the image using a snippet similar to this:-

Like this:-

```
{% if animal.get_latest_medium_url %}
    <img id="animal_image" class="img-rounded left" src="/media/{{ animal_image }}" />
{% endif %}
```

The `get_latest_medium_url` is a method in my `Merchant class` and it computes the url there.